# Create OnlineMeeting in MS Graph with Call-in Info

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am building some utilities to automate aspects of Microsoft Teams at my company.  One thing we are trying is automating scheduling/creation of Online Meetings under various circumstances.  Overall this is working fine, but I can't figure out how to get / attach telephone call-in information for the calls we're creating.

Here's an example `POST /app/onlineMeetings`:

```
{
    "meetingType": "meetNow",
    "participants": {
        "organizer": {
            "identity": {
                "user": {
                    "id": "<user-id>"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "subject": "Personal Room"
}
```

And here's what a typical response looks like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#app/onlineMeetings/$entity",
    "joinUrl": "<join-url>",
    "subject": "Personal Room",
    "isCancelled": false,
    "meetingType": "MeetNow",
    "accessLevel": "SameEnterprise",
    "id": "<meeting-id>",
    "audioConferencing": null,
    "meetingInfo": null,
    "participants": {
        "organizer": {
            "upn": "<user-name>",
            "sipProxyAddress": "<user-name>",
            "identity": {
            }
        },
        "attendees": []
    },
    "chatInfo": {}
}
```

As you can see, the `audioConferencing` key is `null`.  If a user accesses the `joinUrl`, they can join the call and audio conferencing information is displayed at that time -- but I can't figure out how to get it out in advance (e.g. to send in an email).

Also note that since this is not a VTC-enabled meeting, the `id` can't be used to issue a new GET request for additional information, as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: Could you please check if PSTN Calling is enabled for your tenant? I tried it in a tenant where it is enabled and I could get the audioconferencing information.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANyn7.png

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT yes, PSTN is enabled.   I can get audio calling info for meetings created through the MS Teams app, but it's not there for meetings created through this API.

Comment: we are introducing meeting creation with user authentication token in the request, that'll allow to get audio conferencing info. This is something which is being implemented.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thanks for the update!  I'll keep an eye out for the updated API.

Comment: @Benj Did you get any update on this?

Comment: Also, @Benj are you able to see this meeting on the channel in teams?

Comment: @dhruvil29 i ended up deprioritizing this project, so no updates